# hide main content component for some menu items, joomla 1.7

Tags: php, joomla1.7, joomla-template

I know how to hide the main component from the homepage, what I need is to do the same thing for all my menu items also. Basically, what I want is to create multiple homepages, so every category I choose has certain modules that display content.

**How to show only modules, not the article when you click on a menu item (if it is linked to a single article)?**

I know I can use some of the extensions that can embed modules to an article, but don't want to do it like that. I know that there are components that simulate homepages, don't want it like that either.

I hope my question is clear enough, I'm using Joomla 1.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a simple solution!

Installed T3 framework, which allows the removal of main content component for the menu items you choose.